# Removing Kong route prefix

Tags: kubernetes, kong

I have a service with ingress of `/api/my-service`

My kong configuration look like this:

```
services:
  - name: myService
    protocol: http
    host: myservice.mynamespace
    port: 8080
    path: /
    plugins:
      - name: jwt
        config:
           key_claim_name: iss
           claims_to_verify:
             - exp
    routes:
      - tags:
          - OAS3_import
          - OAS3file_openapi.json
        name: myservice-backend
        methods:
          - GET
        paths:
          - /api/my-service/v0/contexts
        strip_path: false
      - tags:
```

When I request `http://kongProxy/api/my-service/v0/myEndpoint` I want kong to create an upstream request like `http://my-service/v0/myEndpoint`

I thought I can use the strip_path setting, but that strips the suffix, not the prefix.

I looked at the request transformer but looks like an overkill for something like that. And I prefer to avoid it because the cong image has been provided to me and would like to avoid having to request modifications.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To get what you desire, your config should look like:

```
services:
  - name: myService
    protocol: http
    host: myservice.mynamespace
    port: 8080
    path: /
    plugins:
      - name: jwt
        config:
           key_claim_name: iss
           claims_to_verify:
             - exp
    routes:
      - tags:
          - OAS3_import
          - OAS3file_openapi.json
        name: myservice-backend
        methods:
          - GET
        paths:
          - /api/my-service
        strip_path: true
      - tags:
```

Then, a request to

http://kongProxy/api/my-service/v0/myEndpoint

will be sent to

http://myservice.mynamespace:8080/v0/myEndpoint

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with regex matching. If you create a regex group that matches the prefix*, the strip path will remove that not the unmatched suffix. Sorry, I am not in a position to test this right now.

https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/how-kong-works/routing-traffic/#using-regex-in-paths